# Como executar comandos de um executavel ubuntu no php?

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu

executo no ubuntu a seguinte linha:

```
needle alvo.txt modelo.txt
```

ao executar ele apresenta essas linhas:

```
Needleman-Wunsch global alignment of two sequences
```

necessito dar um enter para ir como default nessa:

```
Gap opening penalty [10.0]:
```

e nessa:

```
Gap extension penalty [0.5]:
```

e mais um enter para ter o arquivo final nessa linha :

```
Output alignment [hba_human.needle]:
```

como colocaria esses comandos para serem executados no codigo php?

tentei executando o comando `shell_exec ('needle alvo.txt modelo.txt')` o problema está que o programa não é um executável de uma linha necessito dar os Enters para ir como default as outras linhas.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10666844

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode escrever um script em *expect* e chama-lo do seu código PHP. Exemplo:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

set timeout 10
set alvo [lindex $argv 0]
set modelo [lindex $argv 1]

spawn ./needle $alvo $modelo
expect "Gap opening"    {send "\r"}
expect "Gap extension"  {send "\r"}
expect "Gap alignment"  {send "\r"}
```

Esse script basicamente executa a sua linha de comando e espera pelos retornos "Gap..." para enviar o "Enter".